# Best way to compare performance of R-tree and variants?

Tags: performance, data-structures, geometry, spatial-index, r-tree

I am a beginner looking to measure and compare the performance of R-tree vs R*-tree vs Hilbert R-tree vs Priority R-tree for a school assignment. I am not married to comparing these particular ones, but it must be an R-tree vs similar alternatives. What would be the easiest and/or fastest way to compare the performance of these? Filling them up with spatial data, measuring times and plotting a few graphs to compare?

Comment: The performance of data structure is generally very dependant of the actual data and actual operations done on it. Thus, the most important thing is to build a benchmark that is representative to your specific use-case. Otherwise, the conclusion will not match with what you will observe in your real-world application resulting in a huge wast of time (as the benchmark would be useless). For the dataset, you need to care about the statistical distribution. For the operation, you need to care about the proportion of insertion/deletion and their order.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In addition to what @JérômeRichard said, R-Tree can often be configured with different node sizes which also affects performance. Also, I found that different implementations of the same algorithms usually have different performance. Performance comparisons are hard.

Comment: I did a comparison as part of my [TinSpin project](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin), it compares 2 R*Tree implementations, an X-Tree and and STR-R-Tree against several non-R-Trees across 3 data types (uniform, clustered, map) on different operations with different dataset sizes and dataset dimensionalikty. Results are [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin/blob/master/doc/benchmark-2017-01/Diagrams.pdf).

Comment: Another thing to decide is whether you want to test point data or rectangle data.